# Error 999998 when saving raster dataset after using any raster algebra functions in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, error-999998

I'm getting the following error without any documentation whenever I attempt to save a raster dataset after having used any algebraic functions (with any other raster or constant):

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\interact.py", line 575, in OnEditExecClipboard
> >         exec o in **main**.**dict**
> >       File "", line 95, in 
> >     RuntimeError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error.

I've tried to minimize memory utilization by going as far as breaking it down into as many small pieces as I can and deleting the variables after using them. I've also tried using Plus(,) instead of +, Times(,) instead of *, taking things outside of loops and doing them individually, and nothing. I can save the output of any other function *as long as there was never any algebra involved in the leadup* Any suggestions? Here's one version of my code:

```
import arcpy as arc
arc.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\hp\Documents\Work\EE_Model"
arc.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984 UTM Zone 014N")
arcpy.env.cellSize = "MINOF"

# Set up Soil Raster
...

# Create Soil sub-Rasters

arc.conversion.PolygonToRaster("Soil_Cut.shp","N_G1","N_G1.tif",cellsize = 200.0)
arc.conversion.PolygonToRaster("Soil_Cut.shp","N_G2","N_G2.tif",cellsize = 200.0)
arc.conversion.PolygonToRaster("Soil_Cut.shp","N_G3","N_G3.tif",cellsize = 200.0)

print "Soils Converted"

N_G1 = arc.sa.Int("N_G1.tif")
arc.sa.EucAllocation(N_G1).save("N_G1.tif")
N_G1 = "N_G1.tif"

N_G2 = arc.sa.Int("N_G2.tif")
arc.sa.EucAllocation(N_G2).save("N_G2.tif")
N_G2 = "N_G2.tif"

N_G3 = arc.sa.Int("N_G3.tif")
arc.sa.EucAllocation(N_G3).save("N_G3.tif")
N_G3 = "N_G3.tif"

print "Soils Interpolated"

arc.sa.Times(N_G1,0.05).save("N_G1.tif")
```

EDIT: I should also note that trying to call a method like .minimum or .maximum results in this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\interact.py", line 575, in OnEditExecClipboard
> >         exec o in **main**.**dict**
> >       File "", line 22, in 
> >     RuntimeError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error.

Comment: arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\hp\Documents\Work\EE_Model"

Comment: Nope, that doesn't change anything... I should also add that trying to call methods like .minimum and .maximum results in another error.

Comment: Save to grid format?

Comment: Also arcpy.Raster( ng1) might help.

Comment: Esri GRID didn't work either. What do you mean by arcpy.Raster might help? if you meant putting it around the times output before saving that didn't do anything. Same error.

Comment: I don't think the error is with the export---I'm able to do that with other functions. I think something about raster algebra is messed up.

Comment: Try to remove rasters from temp folder, where arcgis saves intermediate results.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug, and the [ArcGIS 10.5.1 (Desktop, Engine, Server) Spatial Analyst Zonal Statistics Tool Patch](https://support.esri.com/en/download/7582) is available to resolve it:

> Esri recommends installing this patch to prevent execution error
>   999998 in deeply nested map algebra expression with large data or
>   incorrect output with 8 bit input raster from Zonal Statistics.