# Error 999998 Saving Raster with Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.6, error-999998

To start, I found a similar question posted on stack exchange [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263937/error-999998-when-saving-raster-dataset-after-using-any-raster-algebra-functions), but I am not using the zonal statistics tool, which the answer to that question is based on.

With that out of the way, I'm attempting to write a very simple arcpy script.
The purpose of the script is to reclassify the values of an input raster, and save the output to a folder.

Currently I'm using this script in a toolbox. I am using arcpy "GetParameterAsText" to determine the input file and output folder.
I have tried using raw file paths instead of using GetParameter, but the script still fails. The file paths I use never include spaces, so I think that can be ruled out.

Here is the code:

```
#Import libraries
import arcpy, sys, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#Have tried GetParameter as well as raw file paths/names
input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
saveFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (1)

#Have confirmed following line works using the python window within arcmap
planAreas = Reclassify(input, "VALUE", RemapRange([[100, 169, 0], [170, 179, 1]])) 

planAreas.save(saveFolder) #Crashes here
```

If I run just the "Reclassify" function in the ArcMap python window, it successfully saves an output as a feature class in Default.gdb.
Running the very same code, but in an python script using the save function, crashes with the dreaded error 999998.

I am using Arc version 10.6.1

Comment: You should always avoid using Python built-in functions such as `input()` as variables: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`planAreas.save(saveFolder)` should be a file path not a folder path.